# Good sources to learn new words for animation?

Tags: discussion, resources

One thing I'm hoping to become able to do is to understand Japanese animation, but the one thing I lack right now is vocabulary: I know some thousands words, but in each and every show (or books) I try to follow the words I don't know are more than the ones I know; and those I learn in one work seems to almost never appear in the following ones I read/watch.

I know each genre has specific vocabulary, but I was wondering: is there any good source to learn commonly used words in animation?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think sub2srs is the way to go if you want to watch Anime without subs.

Pick any Anime you want and parse through sub2srs and learn the vocabulary from it. There is detailed information on youtube and you can take a quick look at:

https://massimmersionapproach.com/

to give you insight as to how to use sub2srs to watch anything in Japanese. As for manga sentence mining is the way to go. Build vocabulary cards you don't know into anki, study them, then enjoy reading the manga you live/love.

Again the above is explained in MIA website. It's a bit tedious when you start but once you build your vocabulary it will be a breeze.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [kamesan.net](https://kamesan.net/) It enables the user to create Anki cards on the fly from subtitles while watching an anime show, and only for those words you don't know. The application will add a video excerpt from the anime to the Anki card as well.